# How are the letters translated?

Tags: translation, control-z

I was watching this new serie [Control Z (2020)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_Z_(TV_series)), and then I was impressed to see even papers had been translated:

[image: Letter with text in Portuguese]

The original language was Spanish, but all the text messages were in Portuguese, and even the papers, like this letter.

How do they do that?
Do they record scenes like this in many languages, or is this a programmatic thing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This can be done in post. I've done it myself in a short product demo video. In my case it was animated text on a smartwatch. It wasn't hard to do that.

One way to do it is filming with a blank paper, automatically track it's movement in the animation software and link the replacement text to the tracking object so that the text follows the sheet of paper, giving you the impression it is printed on the paper. Finally add effects on the text to match the field of depth, lighting, etc. Sometimes automatic tracking does not work well, in this case more manual work is required.

Comment: A great example of this principle at play is [augmented reality cards](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fm-4GPSnj94). Change the scifi floating text with a realistic image of text on paper and you've pretty much got it. Notice how the floating text seems to be (believably) attached to the credit card. That's a matter of really good tracking

Answer (score -2):

Google does alot of live translation. Most captions on youtube are generated by AI. Some services like [https://translatedmovies.com](https://translatedmovies.com/) have people who transated to another language manually by speaking.

Comment: I don't think the amount of translation is the point, but the fact that all the scenes containing objects with text in a specific language have (seemingly) changed, and how that is achieved.